# Logic for finding right set of numbers from an existing list that count to or less than a number

Tags: c#, algorithm, logic

I want an logic for my below requirement.

I have number say 600. I have another set of numbers (Say 100, 200, 500 etc). I need to implement a logic where I need to find the combinations of these number(100,200,500 etc), that will sum up to 600 or less than that.

I am nowhere near to add any code here. Please shed some light on this for me.

Comment: Please at least try something before posting, it is not mlikely that anyone will write this for you.

Comment: @BenRobinson: I dont want the complete answer. I just want some idea to start with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your comment, if you are looking for an idea to start with, then take a look at the [Knapsack problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem) ([1](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/706838/Bounded-Knapsack-Algorithm)).
This is exactly what you are looking for.

> The knapsack problem or rucksack problem is a problem in combinatorial
>   optimization:
>   Given a set of items, each with a mass and a value,
>   determine the number of each item to include in a collection so that
>   the total weight is less than or equal to a given limit and the total
>   value is as large as possible.
>   It derives its name from the problem
>   faced by someone who is constrained by a fixed-size knapsack and must
>   fill it with the most valuable items.

The links above also has examples of implementing an algorithm for solving the problem.

Comment: These seems to be a reasonable starter. Thanks.